# Reusing jhipter generated classes

Tags: jhipster

I have generated a jdl in a Jhipster project which gave me the entity, services and repository. I also have a normal spring boot project that is not jhipster, how do I copy the entity, service and repository package and use them in my spring boot project?

I have tried to move them buy I am getting error on the meta model classes. My specification class is showing error that class does not exist. e.g ClassName_.id

Answer (score 0):

The metamodel classes are generated by build process, so you must adapt the maven or gradle file from your target project to add the generation of the metamodel. Search for annotation processors.

I don't know your requirements but rather than duplicating code, have you considered extracting your entity classes into a sub project and import it as a dependency of both projects?